# Simple video editor - Rotate and cut operations for MPG clips

Tags: video-editor

Could you,please, advise simple video editor for Ubuntu 10.10 for MPG format.
I need following operations:

**1.** rotate whole video - it was captured head down
**2.** cut part of clip

Can't find these functionality in `pitivi` and `openshot` apps.

thank you for help

screen for openshot clip:
[image]

Comment: sergionni - the maverick version of openshot doesnt have this capability (I think) - install the latest version to get this - add this PPA from here https://launchpad.net/~openshot.developers/+archive/ppa

Answer (score 7):

Suggest use OpenShot as per this step by step:

1. Add you clip to the track:
   [image]
2. Then right click the video imported on the track to rotate:
   [image]
3. Then export your video (note the picture is rotated in the preview)
   [image]
4. Once you video has been exported create a new project and reload your newly rotated video
5. Use the razor tool to cut and split tracks:
   [image]

Comment: can't find rotate operation in right-click context menu(invoked from track)

Comment: see my post edited,please

Comment: I couldn't see the rotate item on the context menu at first, then I clicked on the timeline part not where it says "Track 2"

Answer (score 1):

Use [Kdenlive](http://www.kdenlive.org/), a wonderful non-linear video editor. Despite the KDE in it's name it works just fine on the Gnome desktop. It's probably not quite as simple as pitivi or openshot, but it certainly doesn't have the spaceship-controlboard aesthetic of bigger commercial products.

You probably can get away with using the stock Ubuntu package, though there are also alternative, up-to-date packages available:

http://www.kdenlive.org/user-manual/downloading-and-installing-kdenlive/pre-compiled-packages/ubuntu-packages

Add your footage as a clip, then apply a 'Rotate and Shear' effect from the Video Effects menu. Watch out for the rotation units - they are deci-degrees - so '900'=1 quarter turn.

Have fun!

Comment: @Tyley thank you,rotation is Ok, but can't save or export rotated clip. "Save as" gives me unreadable, 6.6 kB file.

Comment: Hi @sergioni - not sure 'save as' is the correct option - it saves the project file, not the video! I think you want to hit 'Render' to save the finished video - you can choose your format from there.